# Some Strange Minimum and proof

Tags: metric-spaces, contest-math, normed-spaces

I read following on Norm chapter in one book.

$$\begin{align}\left|\left\|x-y\right\|-\left\|w-z\right\|\right| \leq &
    \min \{\|x-w\| + \|y-z\| , \|x-z\| + \|y-w\|\}\\\text{ or, }&\min \{\|x-z\| + \|y-w\| , \|x-y\|+\|w-z\| \}\end{align}$$

I need some proof or hint's how this is true...

Comment: use \| to write the norm lines ;)

Comment: What is the meaning of the 'or' in you inequality?

Comment: dear @daw, i edit it. thanks from useful hints.

Comment: this is just the reverse triangle inequality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality

Comment: dear @daw, yes, our instructor says, but i couldn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to show that:
$$\left\|x-y\right\|-\left\|w-z\right\|\leq \|x-w\| + \|y-z\| $$
$$\left\|w-z\right\|-\left\|x-y\right\|\leq \|x-w\| + \|y-z\| $$
$$\left\|x-y\right\|-\left\|w-z\right\|\leq  \|x-z\| + \|y-w\| $$
$$\left\|w-z\right\|-\left\|x-y\right\|\leq  \|x-z\| + \|y-w\|$$
and so on.
But this follows directly from  triangle inequality.
For example, the first inequality:
$$\left\|x-y\right\|\leq \left\|(w-z)+(x-w)+(z-y)\right\|\leq \left\|w-z\right\|+ \|x-w\| + \|y-z\| $$

Comment: would you please add  more detail? i confused...